# Multidimensional Arrays - Sort-function with count beginning at 100

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

For a chart-graphic (where I display the winner and looser of the week) I need multidimensional arrays, and therefore the following function to sort them:

```
function sort_winner($a,$subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    if ($_GET["winner"] == 1) { arsort($b); } else { asort($b); }
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}

$winner = sort_winner($winner,$sortoption);
```

So far, so good. Everything is working!

Now I'd like to display only users who have more than the count of 100 on one of its array. So sort them out.  How to put this additional info into this function? I'm not quite familiar with this, so hopefully somebody could help me, please?!

Comment: php :-) So it's a tiny modification of the function above.

Comment: OK - I've added the `php` tag for you now - try to always tag appropriately in future in order to ensure that you get appropriate answers

Comment: `Now I'd like to display only users who have more than the count of 100 on one of its array` What does this mean???

Comment: @Walkerneo Array1=150, Array2=57, Array3=47, Array4=200, Array5=300.... so I'd like to display only Array1 (for 150), Array4 (for 200) and the Array5 (for 300).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rewriting your arrays to do this, a better way would be to use the built-in [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) or [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort) functions. With these, you can implement your own sorting callback and achieve this much more easily:

```
function winner_sort($a, $b) {
    global $key;
    return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
}

$key = $sortoption;
uasort($winner, 'winner_sort');

if ($_GET['winner'] == "1") {
    $winner = array_reverse($winner);
}
```

In terms of "displaying only users who have more than the count of 100", you want to filter:

```
function winner_filter($item) {
    global $key;
    return $item[$key] > 100;
}

$winner = array_filter($winner, 'winner_filter');
```

(Also: if you can help it, avoid that `$key` global. I'm not sure what your use case is though. If you have to do that, an anonymous function using PHP 5.3 with `uses ($key)` would be a better idea, or in a class property for <5.3)